# Export a excel file and save witout any dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am exporting a excel file using the responce object like,

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
```

It is opening a dialog box (open/save/cancel).But Now I don't need the dialog box.

I want to directly SAVE file without dialog. Can any body help me out with some code link/any?

Comment: That would be a security problem for sure. If web sites could save files without your knowledge that is.. unless I am missing what you meant.

Comment: I think you are using IE. are you facing this in chrome and FF?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Sorry, but what do you think if you open web page and this page write some file on you hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Export.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            var swr = new StringWriter();
            var tw = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
            grd.RenderControl(tw);
            Response.Write(swr.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
            tw.Close();
            swr.Close();
```

Comment: Complete source: http://geekswithblogs.net/nharrison/archive/2013/02/13/build-a-custom-view-engine-to-create-excel-files-in.aspx